# Slow rendering of Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am rendering a partial View in another view via MVC 3 AJAX. But the rendering is painfully slow. for 1350 records it takes about 5-8 seconds. I have checked my data & business layers and have not found any issue. The issue seems to be arising when the partial form is being "inserted" in the main view. I am using Razor for the view.
Any advice ?

Comment: have you tried returning JSON  rather than a view and looping through the json instead, maybe using jquery templates ???  if the problem is rendering then i always find JSON is the most versatile to work with.

Comment: @minus4: Are you advising me to create jason object in controller & then returning it to view & then parse it to form a view ?

Comment: am saying that if your using AJAX, its really simple and easy to just bring back HTML, but its also really easy to use JSON and less problems and no Partial Views etc needed i cant think of any reason why your page would be slow when rendering i have used jquery templates on a few sites too and i get the jquery template with one request and then fill it with json data.  Either way its an option  your action will be a public JsonResult  rather than action results and you return Json(model);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the "painfully slow" part comes from the amount of data pushed to the client, not the 1350 records, as you have found.  Consider using techniques to minimize the amount of data being passed over the wire and underlying HTML.  JSON could help by using AJAX and building the UI through JavaScript, using a JavaScript library.

OR, instead of JSON, just make an AJAX request to the partial view, and render the partial view asynchronously, which would also give the user more of a richer feel; they can access the page, but have to wait for the 1350 results.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The second approach may not be useful coz the screen is used for searching & fetching records fom DB. The result set is to be displayed via AJAX without refreshing/postback of the entire page. 
I guess I'll have to try out the first suggestion. 
I am new to JSON. Any tutorials would help ...

Comment: Tutorials depend on the framework you want to use, so are you using JQuery, or straight MS AJAX?

Comment: As of now it was AJAX in MVC. But if I am to use JSON, I think JQuery would be a better option.